# Does std::cout affect the result of compilation?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I am using C++ to take in a string with some words, which are separated by any number of spaces, and print out the first letter of each word.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str = "hi     my name  is      rex";
    int i = 0;
    int len = str.length();
    while (i < len) {
        // cout << " blah ";        // <--- Note this line
        cout << str[i];
        while (str[i] != ' ') ++i;
        while (str[i] == ' ') ++i;
    }
}
```

If I run this piece of code, I will get a runtime error ([see here](https://ideone.com/5rxAyE)).

However, if I un-comment the "blah" line, I will get "success" and " blah h blah m blah n blah i blah r" is printed ([see here](https://ideone.com/4JA46n)).

I know I probably should check i < len inside those two nested while loops, but what I'm wondering is why does printing the "blah" line make so much difference to the result of compilation.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: What's the error? Post it here as text.

Comment: Hi @Carcigenicate, I am using an online ide, and "Runtime error #stdin #stdout 0s 15240KB" is all I got. But since the string is hard-coded inside the main function, probably I don't need any input? And there're no input for both try, but one of them works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Run the code in a real environment to get a useful error.

Comment: Runtime errors (that go away through adding unrelated code) are usually an indication of *undefined behavior*, in this case caused by the fact that your inner `while` loops will be accessing the string out of bounds

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thank you! @UnholySheep

Comment: @Rex I'd suspect `str[i]` is undefined behavior when `i` goes out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cout` is using a buffer. Until that buffer is flushed the "output" remains in the buffer - memory

But the while loop `while (str[i] != ' ') ++i;` keeps going when the end of string is reached. The online IDE gives the program some time then gives up or segmentation fault occurs